Continuing to get "The developer disk image could not be mounted on this device." on Xcode 15
My Mac is up to date, so is my iPhone, and so is Xcode. I keep getting this error here and nothing seems to work. Have deleted and reinstalled Xcode, restarted my computer, restarted my phone, even reset my iPhone. Been days, and I cannot figure out why this is doing this.
The developer disk image could not be mounted on this device. 
Error mounting image: 0xe8000106 (kAMDMobileImageMounterCredentialsFailed: 
AppleConnect authentication failed or was cancelled.)


I tried running this in terminal and some AppleConnect popup starts showing up and it doesn't accept my Apple ID login information... Does anyone know a fix to this?
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"



Are you trying to launch an app in debug mode via Xcode?Do you have any other iOS devices you can try to launch on? And is this via USB or debug over network?

this is over USB and i'm just trying to run an app normally through Xcode.

Can you try on another mac? And if this is for an existing project, has it ever worked for you? Or can you try creating a new project?

it's always worked before. i dont have access to another mac or another iphone

Any luck creating an Xcode project from scratch? Also, what do you see when you click Show Details on the alert you posted a screenshot of?

new project is showing the same thing, this is what i see when i press show details:
https://textbin.net/v1vyygdx2e

The link doesn't load for me

does this work now? https://textbin.net/v1vyygdx2e

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
